# Interagindo todos os itens de uma lista

Tags: loop, python-2.7, lista

tenho a seguinte situação:

Possuo 4 listas numéricas que vão de 1 a 30. Ex.:

```
AP_X = [1,2,3,4,5...30]
AP_Y = [1,2,3,4,5...30]
demanda_X = [1,2,3,4,5...30]
demanda_Y = [1,2,3,4,5...30]
```

- Possuo uma outra lista, vazia, chamada `distancia` que receberá o resultado dessas interações.

  ```
  distancia = []
  ```
- As listas `AP_X` e `AP_Y` representam as coordenadas de um ponto e as listas `demandas_X` e `demanda_Y`, representam as coordenadas de outro ponto.
- Preciso fazer que cada ponto `AP(x,y)` combine com cada ponto `demanda(x,y)`.
- Por exemplo:

  ```
  distancia = [1,1,1,1 | 1,1,2,2 | 1,1,3,3 |...| 2,2,1,1 | 2,2,2,2| ...| 30,30,1,1 | 30,30,2,2 ]
  ```

Não sei se fui claro, mas preciso combinar todos os item `AP(x,y)` com todos `demanda(x,y)`.

Desde já grato pela ajuda.

Comment: De fato não deu para entender que tipo de combinação você precisa. Consegue explicar melhor?

Comment: Por exemplo: Digamos que eu tenha uma lista com [ a,b,c]  e outra lista com [e,f,g]. Preciso que o resultado seja [ae,af,ag,be,bf,bg,ce,cf,cg].

Comment: Porém, no meu exemplo o abcdefg = coordenadas xy,

Comment: Desculpe-me se não estou claro. Estou me esforçando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AP_X = [1,2,3,4,5,30]
AP_Y = [1,2,3,4,5,30]
demanda_X = [1,2,3,4,5,30]
demanda_Y = [1,2,3,4,5,30]

ap = list(zip(AP_X, AP_Y))
demanda = list(zip(demanda_X, demanda_Y))

distancia = []

for i in ap:
  for j in demanda:
    distancia.append((i, j))

print(distancia)
```

Esse código imprime o seguinte resultado:

```
[((1, 1), (1, 1)), ((1, 1), (2, 2)), ((1, 1), (3, 3)), ((1, 1), (4, 4)), ((1, 1), (5, 5)), ((1, 1), (30, 30)), ((2, 2), (1, 1)), ((2, 2), (2, 2)), ((2, 2), (3, 3)), ((2, 2), (4, 4)), ((2, 2), (5, 5)), ((2, 2), (30, 30)), ((3, 3), (1, 1)), ((3, 3), (2, 2)), ((3, 3), (3, 3)), ((3, 3), (4, 4)), ((3, 3), (5, 5)), ((3, 3), (30, 30)), ((4, 4), (1, 1)), ((4, 4), (2, 2)), ((4, 4), (3, 3)), ((4, 4), (4, 4)), ((4, 4), (5, 5)), ((4, 4), (30, 30)), ((5, 5), (1, 1)), ((5, 5), (2, 2)), ((5, 5), (3, 3)), ((5, 5), (4, 4)), ((5, 5), (5, 5)), ((5, 5), (30, 30)), ((30, 30), (1, 1)), ((30, 30), (2, 2)), ((30, 30), (3, 3)), ((30, 30), (4, 4)), ((30, 30), (5, 5)), ((30, 30), (30, 30))]
```

Onde cada item é do formato `((AP_X, AP_Y), (demanda_X, demanda_Y))`

Lhe serve ou precisa necessariamente ser no formato `AP_X, AP_Y, demanda_X, demanda_Y`?

Comment: Perfeito, Anderson!
É exatamente como eu preciso.
Muito, Muito Obrigado.

Abraço amigo.